# Bézier control points for drawing an interpolating cubic spline *function*

Tags: curves, bezier-curve

Related to my previous question about [the type of curve Photoshop's Curves interface uses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675064/what-type-of-curve-does-photoshops-curves-use), it seems it uses an **interpolating cubic spline function**: for a set of *x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>* pairs defined by the user, we can find a cubic spline *f(x)* such that *f(x<sub>i</sub>) = y<sub>i</sub>* for all the points.

On the other hand, [this clear explanation](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/149.1.02w/handouts/dd_splines.pdf) has helped me draw the **basis spline** (Section 4) and the **natural spline** (Section 5) for the *x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>* pairs with SVG Bézier paths, but these are **parametric** curves where *x* and *y* are both functions of *t*.

I feel like I may be circling the obvious, but I'm having a hard time applying this knowledge to derive the Bézier control points for a non-parametric curve, where *y = f(x)*. (Section 7 of the aforementioned paper makes it sound like it should be apparent how to do it)

**Edit 1:** Looks like my question [may be overlapping with this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599669/find-control-points-to-produce-a-given-curve), where one answer suggests either a Catmull-Rom or a Natural spline. So I guess what's not clear is how to use any of these techniques to obtain curves that still retain the aspect of a function (i.e. no multiple *y* values for a single *x*)?

Comment: [This is a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273377/conditions-that-guarantee-a-composite-bezier-curve-in-the-cartesian-plane-repres?rq=1) wherein the knots are evenly spaced on the _x_ axis, but what if they're not?

Comment: A non-parametric curve $y=f(x)$ is identical to a parametric curve $x=t,y=f(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catmull-Rom and Natural spline are both ways for creating a cubic spline curve interpolating a given set of points. Typically, the curve will be in parametric form where x and y are both function of t. For parametric spline interpolation, assigning a parameter to each data point is the most essential step, which is often referred as parametrization. Typically, we will use either chord-length or centripetal parametrization.

If you need "cubic spline function", all you need to do is to use $t=(x-x_{min})/(x_{max}-x_{min})$ for parametrization where $x_{min}$ is the smallest $x$ value and $x_{max}$ the largest $x$ value among your data points. You can choose either Catmull-Rom or Natural spline to construct your "spline function". Afterwards, evaluating the spline function will simply require an additional step to convert $x_i$ to $t_i$ as $t_i=(x_i-x_{min})/(x_{max}-x_{min})$.

Comment: After much contemplation I _think_ I understand the process. Am I right to say that [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Algorithm_to_find_the_interpolating_cubic_spline) describes the reparametrization of the Bézier curve?

Comment: yes. It is a form of reparametrization.