# I need a spline type that interpolates through knot points and produces a single-valued y=f(x)

Tags: curves, spline, bezier-curve

I have a set of $(t, f(t))$ points that describe a function of time. I need to interpolate those with a spline that goes through all the given points, and doesn't have any loops, so it creates a single-valued C2-continuous function of t. All the spline types I've looked at, primarily centripetal Catmull-Rom and interpolating b-splines, don't have the single-valued property. If I place two knot points very close to each other on the t axis, the spline may loop around (go backwards in t) because with those splines they're really in $(x,y)$ and the $t$ is along the curve length.

I've looked at [Bézier control points for drawing an interpolating cubic spline *function*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678997/b%c3%a9zier-control-points-for-drawing-an-interpolating-cubic-spline-function) which says it's just a matter of reparamaterization where $t=(x-x_{min})/(x_{max}-x_{min})$, but I don't see how that removes the looping. Could someone explain it simply?

Comment: Use natural cubic spline with x(t) = t and y(t)=f(t), then you can avoid loops. Catmull-Rom spline is not C2.